# How to change LinkedIn follow company button size?

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to be able to control the size of the LinkedIn follow company button (described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/follow-company-plugin), but I can't find good documentation on other options available for the button. Loads of links is dead / points to old API documentation.

I am open to create a custom button, but would typically need a one-click experience when you logged into LinkedIn (like it is with LinkedIn button above - when you logged in)

A few things I've tried:

- Finding official documentation for the LinkedIn button above - even something like changing the count from bottom to the right/top isn't documented anywhere I could find (but I was able to do this by guessing the parameter value)
- I can see the LinkedIn button above uses an IFRAME from a different domain, so I couldn't get plain CSS styling to work like normal to objects inside the IFRAME, and JavaScript manipulation is blocked by cross-site scripting restrictions.
- One thing that "almost" worked is trying CSS zoom property on the IFRAME, but proved to have bad rendering on some browser/screen combinations (Chrome on non-retina seemed to be an issue in my environment) - there are loads of stackoverflow articles on trying to resolve blurry zoom issues, but couldn't get those to work either. I will post that solution here once I know there is no other official way to do this
- I looked through the API documentation to see if there is a way I can code my own button, but it all seemed to include an authorization step (I would like the user to have only 1 click as per linkedIn button). Any guidance on API end-points/JavaScript APIs to use would be appreciated.